# How to call javascript function with two Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I pass a html element value specifically a jquery spinner object to a JavaScript function so I can put the values on a row?.

Which are just two items in the html

```
  <input id="timeWorkedHours" name="value" style="width:100px;">
    </td>
    <td style="width:3%">
        </td>
    <td style="width:10%">
        hours
    </td>
    <td style="width:3%">
        <input id="timeWorkedMins" name="value" style="width:100px;">
    </td>
```

I call the function below on a button type so I need the value of the two spiner objects how do I get that? and pass to a function?

```
<input type="button" id="resolutiontimeaddbutton" value="Add"  onclick="resolutiontimeaddbutton()" style="width:90px" />
```

This is the function

```
function addResolutionTimeToGrid(hours,secs)
{

       $("#affecteditemstable tr:last").before("<tr style='height:10px;vertical-align:top'><td><div>" + tableDataAI[AIcount].First + "</div></td><td><div>" + tableDataAI[AIcount].Second + "</div></td><td><div>" + tableDataAI[AIcount].Third + "</div><td><div>" + tableDataAI[AIcount].Fourth + "</div></td><td></td></tr>");
    AIcount++;

 }


}
```

Comment: If using jQuery, don't use inline `onlick=` for starters. Attach an event to the control using jQuery.

Comment: did not get your question. what are the objects you want to pass?

Comment: Give your `input`s a type, don't give them the same `name`...

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery, don't use inline onlick= for starters. Attach an event to the control using jQuery

**It also does not help that you are calling the wrong function name:** (`resolutiontimeaddbutton` instead of `addResolutionTimeToGrid`)

However: You could do something like this (assuming you mean mins and not seconds as there is no seconds control):

```
<input type="button" id="resolutiontimeaddbutton" value="Add"  onclick="addResolutionTimeToGrid($('#timeWorkedHours').val(), $('#timeWorkedMins').val())" style="width:90px" />
```

To do it jQuery style:

```
$(function(){
    $('#resolutiontimeaddbutton').click(function(){
        addResolutionTimeToGrid($('#timeWorkedHours').val(), $('#timeWorkedMins').val())
    });
});
```

Note: `$(function(){ your code here});` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready({your code here});`

Comment: @David Buckley: What on Earth are you talking about? Bard account? Spelling? posh schools? eh? Please explain your sudden abuse. Thanks

Comment: my account has just been band for no reason what so ever before that commenting my question

Comment: I have marked your offensive comments for moderation so they are now invisible. Apologies if that does contribute to you being barred from SO. I tried to help here, so not sure what went wrong for you :)

Comment: it wasnt that that did it was before that

Comment: Of course. I meant I hope that does not add to your problems :) Back to point at hand, was the above answer helpful? You have not provided any feedback on it.

Comment: StackOverflow only has temporary bans that I know of, so you might want to *chillax* a bit, or no-one will want to help :)